# Read BLOB from Oracle Database in Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, blob, node-oracledb

I am trying to read a `BLOB` data type from Oracle using a nodejs from npm package called `oracledb` and this is my select statement, it hold picture in it:

```
select media from test_data
```

I have tried using a few solution but it doesn't work.

Here is my response from the `res.json`:

```json
{
        "MEDIA": {
            "_readableState": {
                "objectMode": false,
                "highWaterMark": 16384,
                "buffer": {
                    "head": null,
                    "tail": null,
                    "length": 0
                },
                "length": 0,
                "pipes": [],
                "flowing": null,
                "ended": false,
                "endEmitted": false,
                .....
   
    },
```

How do I get the hex value of it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with the node.js code you have attempted; the errors that you get and what your expected output is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing an instance of the node-oracledb [Lob class](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#lobclass) which you can stream from.

However, it can be easiest to get a Buffer directly.  Do this by setting `oracledb.fetchAsBuffer`, for example:

```js
oracledb.fetchAsBuffer = [ oracledb.BLOB ];

const result = await connection.execute(`SELECT b FROM mylobs WHERE id = 2`);

if (result.rows.length === 0)
  console.error("No results");
else {
  const blob = result.rows[0][0];
  console.log(blob.toString());  // assuming printable characters
}
```

Refer to the documentation [Simple LOB Queries and PL/SQL OUT Binds](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#queryinglobs).